# Finding maximum subset-triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

To a given base (ab), triangles are constructed by choosing a point (p).
How can i find the maximum subset-triangles(*)? [image: ...]

(*)subset-triangle: p' is inside the triangle abp. Allowed interceptions from ap' and bp' with ap and bp are only a, b.
[image: green: valid | red: invalid]

My current solution, needs number-of-points! appends to find the maximum.

Comment: So you want to know how to find which point p forms the triangle abp with the most other points contained within? You would need x,y coordinates for the set of potential p points as well as a and b.

Comment: Exactly. I have the coordinates. As I wrote above I mean looking for a solution which is faster than n!

Comment: mean=m (can't edit comments)

Comment: I would write a function to check if a point is part of the interior of a triangle and loop over it with every point for every triangle. After adding up all the true or false returns for each triangle in a list I'd print the largest item in the list. I see no faster way.